# How to access this element in RStudio

Tags: r, rstudio

[image]

Can someone please tell me how I can access alpha0?
I tried the following:`test$alpha0`, `test[alpha0]`, `test["alpha0"]`, `test[[alpha0]]`, `test[["alpha0"]]`, `getElement(test, alpha0)` all of which don't work.

Can anyone please also explain the logic behind the notation in RStudio with the dollars as shown in the picture?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: would you please give a reproducible example.

Comment: @AhmedSalhin It is a "Large MCMC" object from the `bayesGARCH` package. Giving you the code to obtain the object would take you long, as it performs a large amount of simulations.

Comment: I mean just subset the object `test`, use `dput` and post it. Is that possible?

Comment: I guess `colnames(test)` may work, because it appears to be a `matrix` object. Otherwise. `attr(test,"dimnames")[[2]]` may also work. This to have the column names. If you want the column, `test[,"alpha0"]` is likely to work.

Comment: I have kind of the same object and attributes(test)[[2]][2] worked with it.

Comment: @nicola Thanks a lot, `test[,"alpha0"]` did what I wanted! If you write an answer I will accept it. Could you also please tell me the logic behind using this rather than for instance `test$alpha0`? Because the notation in RStudio almosts suggests that using `$` is the way to go.

Comment: @AhmedSalhin Thanks for your help, it works now indeed :)

Comment: Can anyone tell me why my question is being downvoted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have seems to be a `matrix` and what you showed are the `rownames` and the `colnames`. Just try:

```
test[,"alpha0"]
```

to retrieve the needed column. You cannot use the `$` operator, since a `matrix` is just an array (cannot store data of different types) while `data.frames` are `list` and on then the `$` operator works. Consider this example:

```
  #create a matrix
  m<-matrix(ncol=2,nrow=10)
  #set the column names
  colnames(m)<-c("a","b")
  #this works
  m[,"a"]
  #this doesn't
  m$a
  #coerce to a data.frame
  mdf<-as.data.frame(m)
  #this works
  mdf[,"a"]
  #this also works
  mdf$a
```

Hope this clarifies a little.

Comment: Great, thanks a lot, that clarifies things indeed :)!